# Select specific number of items from a list

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I have a list in format

```
+---------+------------------+
| Country | GDP              |
+---------+------------------+
| Austria | 26171.6909118266 |
+---------+------------------+
| Belgium | 24512.4131357791 |
+---------+------------------+
| Denmark | 32400.0606104087 |
+---------+------------------+
| Spain   |                  |
+---------+------------------+
```

Get data from list using:

```
function parseData(d) {
  var keys = _.keys(d[0]);
  return _.map(d, function(d) {
    var o = {};
    _.each(keys, function(k) {
      if( k == 'Country' )
        o[k] = d[k];
      else
        o[k] = parseFloat(d[k]);
    });
    return o;
  });
}

var xAxisOptions = ["GDP"]
var data = parseData(data);

d3.select('#x-axis-menu')
.selectAll('li')
.data(xAxisOptions)
.enter()
.append('li')
.text(function(d) {return d;})
.classed('selected', function(d) {
  return d === xAxis;
})
.on('click', function(d) {
  xAxis = d;
  updateChart();
  updateMenus();
});
```

The problem is that all the time select the whole list.
I want to select all GDPs until Denmark, does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you wish to stop at denmark or you want to remove all blank values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash is overkill -_-

```
function parseData (d) {
  var i, cp = [];
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i]["GDP"]) cp.push({
      "Country": data[i]["Country"],
      "GDP": parseFloat(data[i]["GDP"])
    });
  }
  return cp;
}
```